# Updating two pair of columns according to other pair of columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, vba

I have 2 sets of three grouped columns in one worksheet. This stretches for  30000 rows. Sample data is below:

```
code    Serial  Amount  code    Serial  Amount
1111    2346    2000000 2222    5555    300000
2222    4567    4000000 3333    6666    700000
3333    4545    7000000 1111    7777    8000000
                        1111    8888    550000
                        1111    9999    600000
```

Some of first *code* column values are repeated in the second code column but in a disordered fashion. I want to match the second *code* column values to the first and update the *Serial* and *Amount* values based on the match. The best way I can describe the logic would be:

```
IF  (Code(1)==Code(2)) 
THEN 
    (Amount(1) ==Amount(2) ) 
 and 
    (Serial(1)==Serial(2))
```

as you see in example *code(2)* column we have three repeated 1111 value but in *code(1)* column we have just one 1111.i want to excel update *serial* *amount* in 1th row if matched for other 2 time's does not exist any 1111 in *code(1)* insert  *serial(2)*    *amount(2)*   *code(2)* as a new row in *serial(1)* *amount(1)* *code(1)*
i trying below code it update unique code but it cant insert repeated code like second and third 1111 with it's serial and amount.

```
Sub checklist()
 Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("a1:a" & LastRow)
For Each cell2 In Range("D1:D" & LastRow)

If cell.Offset(0, 0) <> "" And cell.Offset(0, 0) = cell2.Offset(0, 0) Then
cell2.Offset(0, 0) = cell.Offset(0, 0)
cell2.Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1)
cell2.Offset(0, 2) = cell.Offset(0, 2)

End If
Next
Next
```

End Sub

The results should look like the following.

```
code    Serial  Amount  code    Serial  Amount
1111    7777    8000000 2222    5555    300000
1111    8888    550000  3333    6666    700000
1111    9999    600000  1111    7777    8000000
2222    5555    300000  1111    8888    550000
3333    6666    700000  1111    9999    600000
```